# In which cases you use free energy to calculate pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

From thermodynamic identity you get:
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N} = -P$$
But with Helmholtz free energy $F = U-TS$, we can also get pressure from this equation:
$$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N} = -P.$$
In which cases should you use free energy version?

Comment: Both of them are equivalent. You use the one which best suits your needs.

Comment: As indicated in the index of your function, the first identity apply for S=constant and N=constant while the second one apply for T=constant and N=constant